# QGIS 3 Shortest Path: batch processing?

Tags: qgis, shortest-path

I have some commuting data showing people who cycle to work. The data has residence, workplace and unique ID numbers for each commuter. I have georeferenced the home and work locations so I have two point shapefiles, work and home. I also have a shapefile of the road and cycle route network.

I have done some experimenting and the shortest path algorithm in QGIS 3 allows shortest route analysis of shapefile to point OR point to shapefile (which is super), but I need to calculate a route for EVERY commuter. Is there a way to automate this using the ID number as the base?

From looking into this online it seems that this may be possible using PGRouting in PostGIS, but it would be nice to find a solution avoiding PostGIS because my colleagues do not have access to this.

This stackexchange question alludes to a similar problem, but, again, this user is only using one point. I have not found a stackexchange thread which answers this problem. 
[QGIS 3 - Shortest path layer to layer, not point!](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282790/qgis-3-shortest-path-layer-to-layer-not-point)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ["OSM-Tools"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMtools/)  to do this task.

There is currently a workaround to start routing, you have to select your features first and then start. Further information are available [here](https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice-py).

This Plugin is available from the Plugin-Repository and after you ordered a [key](https://openrouteservice.org/sign-up/) you can start routing.

[image]

Comment: This looks promising - I will experiment with this over the next few days. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: I am struggling to get osm tools to work. I have my two point layers open. I have a valid API key (with credit remaining). I have selected all in both my point layers. OSM tools won't let me select the tables (the drop down ís blank) refresh list does nothing. I have reduced my point tables to a manageable number (3 points each) and I have tried various versions of QGIS 3. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you have an id field (integer) in your point features to select? do you try routing or matrix? I also had struggle with matrix. do you use epsg 4328?

Comment: Do you use the free api key? How many features do you want to route at once?

Comment: Yes, I am using the free API key, I have 0/2500 credit remaining. My ID field was char, but I've made a copy ID field in integer format for both tables - still the same. It doesn't work in Matrix or Routing. For the purposes of testing I am using two points in each table. I am using EPSG 27700 projection, but I don't suppose projection matters?

Comment: Am now getting an occasional error message (though on opening the tool, not when attempting to run). Error is "list index out of range". I am definitely selecting all points in both tables so it isn't error 47 in the tool github issues list.

Comment: i just tested the tool again on QGIS 2.18.22 with two different shapefiles each one feature and id and selected both before starting routing - it worked. I am not sure the projection matters or not, haven't read anything. It worked with epsg 4326.

Comment: It worked quite well in the past.. idk about those issues. which QGIS version do you use?

Comment: I am using the early adopter release (3.01) but I've also tried a clean install of the newest version (3.2). The tool doesn't install on QGIS 2 anymore, you get the error (module X is missing).

Comment: I am going to try a new install on another laptop, I'll let you know how I get on. I think the problem is at my end, I've not heard of any other users having the same issue. You've  been very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Now resolved this, my point tables were origally converted from Mapinfo tables. I had to save a new version as point tables, not point25d which QGIS automatically selected.